# aws credentials working in CLI, not in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have set up my own aws profile on a shared vm:

```
[profile me]
aws_access_key_id = xxxx
aws_secret_access_key = yyyy
region = zzzz
```

and if I try to access resources from s3 by the command line, everything works:

```
> aws s3 cp s3:/bucket/prefix/resource_name . --profile me
download: s3:/bucket/prefix/resource_name to ./resource_name
```

but if I try to access the same resources through Python, I get `403` errors:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='me')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
df = pd.read_csv('s3://bucket/prefix/resource_name')

>> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

any thoughts what's causing the different behavior?

Comment: What is the relationship between `pd` and `s3`? I can't see a link.

Comment: You're not providing the S3 credentials to pd.  You need to specify the credentials with something like `storage_options={'profile': "me"}`